# Bottom owerflow when the keyboard pop up in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Layout is ok when there is no keyboard.
But, when keyboard pop up bottom owerflowed.

How do i fix it?

Comment: wrap your widget in a SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget gets resized whenever your keyboard gets focused as your widget is not scrollable and has finite height. So, what you can do is wrap your hole widget inside a SingleChildScrollView.

For Ex:

```
SingleChildScrollView(child:_buildYourWidget());
```

If your widget consist **column** as **its top most layer** then you should provide column an additional property that is **mainAxisSize** to **minimum**. So that Column will take the required height and SingleChildScrollView will be able to manage your content properly.

```
mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min
```

This will definitely solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. This worked too....

Answer (score 0):

You need a Scroll Widget on top of the others. This is the best way, because the widgets will adjust to the keyboard. However you can also edit your Scaffold with:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

Or, try this one

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
            YourWidgets()
        ]
    )
)
```

Comment: When i put this, keyboard covers a half of the layout.....

Comment: Yeah the resizeToAvoidBottomPadding shouldn‘t be changed. Just as an “emergency”. As I said it would be better if you wrap the whole thing in a scrollable widget. For example a ListView.

Comment: I put my widget in a ListView, and then put the ListView in a Expanded widget. Problem solved.

Comment: By the way, Thank you.